# Show/hide group of divs based on input type= "number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form and script, which works absolutely fine. I am trying to show/hide rows on a table based on the form input.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

}

function repayment() {

  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  var year = z / 12;

  document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = 'Loan to Value: ' + loantovalue.toFixed(1) + '%';
  document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = year + ' years';

}
```

```html
<form name="repaymentcalc" action="">
  <div align="center">
    <br />

    <p>
      Home Value £
      <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
    </p>

    <p>
      Loan Amount £
      <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
    </p>

    <p>
      Interest Rate
      <input type="number" id="interestrate" value="3.00" style="width: 50px">%
    </p>

    Term
    <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">
    <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years</div>

    <div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £948.42</div>
    <p>
      <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I need to have a column say for "max ltv" which will show a figure, say 75. If the value for `var loantovalue = x / h * 100;` is more than 75, then this row is hidden.

How do I group the div's or hide a table row based on the number inputs in the form?

Any help getting started with this would be great please.

Table example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Mortgage Lender</th>
    <th>Max LTV</th>
    <th>SVR</th>
    <th>Fee</th>
    <th>Max Amount</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Length (months)</th>
    <th>Initial Rate</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Halifax</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>3.99</td>
    <td>999</td>
    <td>1000000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>1.19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HSBC</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>3.49</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1000000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>1.49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nationwide</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>3.99</td>
    <td>199</td>
    <td>1000000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>1.49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Yorkshire Building Society</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>2.49</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2000000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>1.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Direct</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>3.99</td>
    <td>999</td>
    <td>750000</td>
    <td>Fixed</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>1.19</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So if "more than 750000" then row "first direct " will not show. If "*more than 60*" then row "Yorkshire Building Society" will not show.

Further to this, I would like a way of having extra columns which will work out monthly repayments based on "Initial Rate" values from the table and the form inputs.

Is this at all possible using a html table, or is a div layout necessary and where do I start? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Where is the table? how are you binding the data to the table?

Comment: jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/show/ and http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, and I didn't want to start until I had some idea of the best method. I just need pointing in the right direction really please?

Comment: The table will be basic. A header row, and then up to 100 rows of data, mostly numerical. It would be better if some cells could show results based on .js calculations, which is why I thought the div route was the best option?

Comment: Sorry @chsdk why is this wrong? It works, but what is the issue with doing it this way?

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use `document.getElementById('id_of_div_or_tr').style.visibility = 'hidden'` or `'visible'`.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, it looks like all you need is an if statement to hide or show.  See my edited snippet below.

Note I also removed the inline styles and added labels, to make it more semantic.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  repayment(); // Call onload to setup with initial values
  
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;
}

function repayment() {

  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  var year = z / 12;

  document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = 'Loan to Value: ' + loantovalue.toFixed(1) + '%';
  document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = year + ' years';

  /**
   *
   * Added this, below
   *
   **/
  var rows = document.getElementById("data").getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var len = rows.length;
  
  // Iterate through each of the rows
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var cell = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]; // Get the second td in this row
    var maxltv = parseInt(cell.innerHTML, 10);
    var rowClass = rows[i].className;
    
    // If the ltv on this row is lower than it's max, and it doesn't have a class="hide" yet, add it
    if(maxltv < loantovalue && rowClass.indexOf('hide') < 0) {
      // Take into accound multiple classes (add a space if necessary)
      rows[i].className = (rowClass.length > 0 ? ' ' : '') + 'hide';
    }
    // If the ltv on this row is higher than, or equal to its max, remove the class="hide"
    else if(maxltv >= loantovalue) {
      rows[i].className = rowClass.replace('hide', '').trim();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
tr.hide {
  display: none;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
#homevalue {
  width: 25px;
}
#loanamount {
  width: 75px;
}
#interestrate {
  width: 50px;
}
#numberpayments {
  width: 100px;
}
#years {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form name="repaymentcalc" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="homevalue">Home Value £</label>
    <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="loanamount">Loan Amount £</label>
    <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="interestrate">Interest Rate</label>
    <input type="number" id="interestrate" value="3.00" />%
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="numberpayments">Term</label>
    <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" />
    <span id="years">25 years</span>
  </p>

  <p id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £948.42</p>
  <p id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</p>
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mortgage Lender</th>
      <th>Max LTV</th>
      <th>SVR</th>
      <th>Fee</th>
      <th>Max Amount</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Length (months)</th>
      <th>Initial Rate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
    <tr>
      <td>Halifax</td>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>3.99</td>
      <td>999</td>
      <td>1000000</td>
      <td>Fixed</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>1.19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HSBC</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>3.49</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1000000</td>
      <td>Fixed</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>1.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nationwide</td>
      <td>90</td>
      <td>3.99</td>
      <td>199</td>
      <td>1000000</td>
      <td>Fixed</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>1.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yorkshire Building Society</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>2.49</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2000000</td>
      <td>Fixed</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>1.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First Direct</td>
      <td>75</td>
      <td>3.99</td>
      <td>999</td>
      <td>750000</td>
      <td>Fixed</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>1.19</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not quite what I needed.

Comment: @J.Ayo Perhaps you should elaborate how it did not fit your needs?

Comment: Sorry, was updating original question. I hope it makes more sense now?

Comment: I updated my answer, now iterating through each of the rows to pick out the cell's value for `maxltv` and hiding the ones under, showing the ones over.

Comment: I also updated it to leverage CSS to hide/show the rows instead of JS.  It adds a `class="hide"` which CSS picks up on to apply `display:none;`